# CEFsharp security

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

We plan to use the CefSharp in our project. Is there any security threat analysis available on the latest version of Cefsharp.Winforms ?IF so please let me know ,is there any security testing documents available ?  What are the vulnerabilities ?

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases/tag/v92.0.260 
Uses the current stable chromium release https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2021/08/stable-channel-update-for-desktop.html

Comment: Chromium doesn't publish security details until months after the bug has been resolved.